# Magnitude of load and cycles needed during testing of bike forks

Tags: frames, fork, safety

I want to do a structural test on bicycle forks. Is there any specific criteria I need to follow of what should be the magnitude of the significant load and also how many cycles would need to be applied for the test ?

Are there any ISO standards which describe this ? I am based in the UK.

Comment: If you Google, you may see the ISO standard 4210-6. Problem is, to access the sections that specify the actual loads, you'll need to pay ISO.

Comment: Any reasonable structural test on bicycle forks, you are going to destroyed and wear out numerous forks. Cost of the ISO standard chicken feed in comparison